# File pattern to use for fetching files from FTP Server in Unix

Tags: unix, find

I've an issue with file name pattern to be provided in order to fetch the pattern file from the FTP server.

Currently, I am using `ABC_YYYYMMDD*.sha1` as the pattern to fetch files. It fetches the last file using the above pattern. Sometimes, .gz.sha1 comes later and sometimes, the other one.

```
ABC_20160801060000.sha1
ABC_20160801060000.txt.gz.sha1
```

I would need to provide the file name pattern in such a way that the file should always pick `ABC_YYYYMMDDHHMISS.sha1` only.

Need a fool proof pattern which matches the required one only?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` `-regex` option for matching these file-names:-

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*ABC_20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.sha1'
```

Am using the `-regex` flag supported by `find` for this over the `-name` flag which does simple glob pattern matching.

The `man` page of `find` says below for the `-regex`:-

```
-regex pattern
           File name matches regular expression pattern. This is a match
           on the whole path, not a search.

-regextype name
           This option controls the variety of regular expression syntax
           understood by the ‘-regex’ and ‘-iregex’ tests. This option is
           positional; that is, it only affects regular expressions which
           occur later in the command line. If this option is not given, GNU 
           Emacs regular expressions are assumed.
```

More about `posix-extended` regex type at this [`page`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). Other supported regex-types can be found [`here`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Regular-Expressions.html).

To see it in action:-

```
$ ls ABC_2016*
ABC_20161231225950.sha1  ABC_20169231225990.sha1

$ find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*ABC_20[0-9]{2}(0[1-9]|1[0-2])([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])([0-2][0-3])([0-5][0-9])([0-5][0-9])\.sha1'
./ABC_20161231225950.sha1
```

**Update:-**

If the `regextype` is not supported in the `find` version, a simple glob construct using the `-name` flag can be used to achieve the same.

```
$ ls ABC_2016*
ABC_20161231225950.sha1  ABC_20169231225990.sha1

$ find . -type f -name 'ABC_2[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-2][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-2][0-5][0-9][0-5][0-9].sha1'
./ABC_20161231225950.sha1
```

Comment: Thanks Inian for the illustrative example. But, I need to issue the find as FTP command. These pattern files are present in the FTP Server. Though 'find' command works on FTP server, the options are not recognized. :(

Comment: @user1999315: refer my update for a solution using the `-name` flag alone.